# Passing int array from C (JNI) to Java and return back an int array from Java to C?

Tags: java, arrays, c, java-native-interface

I am new to java here. I am working on Calling Java methds from C using JNI. I can successfully pass and return int values from  C to Java but I am not able to pass Int array from  C to Java and return back an int array from Java to C. Please let me know how to do so?

Below I have mentioned my generic code. Please let me know how to modify it and acheive ? I have came across many articles for the opposite (passing int array from Java to C). Sorry if it looks like a basic question.

My C code:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"Simple");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
jmethodID addnumber_method=(*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env , cls, "add" , "()V");
    
 (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env,cls, mid, NULL);
  printf("sum is %d\n",(*env)->CallStaticIntMethod(env, cls, addnumber_method , a_num , b_num));
```

My java code:

```
public class simple
{
  public static int add(int a , int b)
  {
    int sum = a+b;
    return sum;
   }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("C calling java");
        
  }
}
```

Comment: The native type is `jintArray`, and you'd create one using `NewIntArray`. Consult [the JNI functions documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: so should I use something like ` jintArray result = (*env)->NewIntArray(env,size);(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result, 0,size , fill);`  but how do I pass the array from C to java ? should my statement be like this : ` (*env)->CallStaticIntMethod(env, cls, add , result);` ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo014, maybe this one will also help you: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo045